# Can I use Spring Security annotations in ZKGrails composers?

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security, zk

Can I use Spring Security annotations in my ZKGrails composers to secure the ajax-callbacks, or can/do i have to inject springSecurityService (and check the principal's authorities, in every method manually)?

Update: According to http://felipecypriano.com/2009/10/26/tweak-zk-to-make-event-processing-call-groovys-invokemethod/ , the annotations should work, and I found the modification mentioned in this post in the current ZKGrails plugin version (1.0.4). Still, when I try to secure methods in my composer, they remain fully accessible.

Comment: What version of spring security core plugin are you using? Also, can we assume you are ONLY using annotations to drive the security mappings in your application and not trying to mix Annotations along with RequestMapping?

Comment: I'm using the latest spring-security-core version (1.1.3), and yes, only annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because "@Secured" annotation is not supported by spring security plug-in. I think you should implement your own method interceptor according http://felipecypriano.com/2009/10/19/enable-secured-annotation-with-grails-spring-security-plugin/ to enable it.

Comment: (Sorry it took me so long to accept - somehow, slipped off my radar)